# How to pass source ip in request headers for an URL using browsermob proxy and selenium using python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, request, browsermob-proxy, browsermob

I want to send source_ip in request headers for any URL.
Can it be done using selenium or browsermob proxy?

After this I want to collect HAR of this URL also. I am aware of HAR collection but not sure how to send source_ip.

I searched a lot but did not get any solution.